# Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected: <(Null)>

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I'm working on Coded Ui test. When I run the my test:

```
 public partial class UIMap
{
    public UIMap()
    {
        this.TestInit();

    } 

    private HandlingUnitDataController huDC = new HandlingUnitDataController();
    public DataTransferHandlingUnit testHU = new DataTransferHandlingUnit();        

    public void pressEnter3()
 {    

          List<DataTransferHandlingUnit> DataList;                      


        DataList = huDC.GetHandlingUnits(null);
        foreach (DataTransferHandlingUnit hu in DataList)
        {

            if (hu.idlabel == this.IdLabelInputParams.UIScannBoxEdit2Text)
            {

                testHU = hu;
                break;
            }

        }           

        Assert.AreEqual(testHU.idlabel,this.IdLabelInputParams.UIScannBoxEdit2Text);  

        }
```

Occurs error:

> Assert.AreEqual failed Expected:<(Null)>

What do I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Can you debug this to confirm that `testHU.idlabel` is not null?  The error message says that you expected `Null` and the expected value in your case is `testHU.idlabel`.

Comment: Yes, testHU.idlabel is not null and expected value is testHU.idlabel. For addinional information, I have 3 more test methods like this one, just for one of them passes test, for the rest occurs the same error like this. expected Null

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that

```
if (hu.idlabel == this.IdLabelInputParams.UIScannBoxEdit2Text)
```

does not evaluate to true therefore your

```
public DataTransferHandlingUnit testHU = new DataTransferHandlingUnit();
```

is still in the testHU reference and testHU.idlabel is null

Comment: My thought is also in this direction, but don't know how to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is this.IdLabelInputParams... its not declared in your code provided.

Comment: `public class IdLabelInputParams 
   {

        #region Fields
        /// <summary>
        /// "982343764598" in "scannBox" text box eingeben
        /// </summary>
        public string UIScannBoxEdit2Text = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 12).Replace("-", "4").Replace("a", "0").Replace("b", "3").Replace("c", "2").Replace("d", "4").Replace("e", "6").Replace("f", "7").Replace("g", "8").Replace("h", "9");
        #endregion
    }  `    

  this.IdLabelInputParams is used to get the random generated value entered by keyboard

Comment: You'd have to debug and step into that testinit where I assume you are setting the values for the test and see why it is not being set.

Comment: Problem is, new generated and entered random number is not included to DataList list. That's why foreach loop can not find any match and at the end returns null.